# A consequence of $\left(\sum_{i=1}^N f_i(t) a_i\right) \cdot b = 0$ $\forall b \in \left(\sum_{i=1}^N a_i\right)^\perp$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, vectors

Let $a_i$ with $i=1, \dots, N$ be vectors in $\mathbb R^3$ and let $f_i: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ with $i=1, \dots, N$ (here $N\ge 2$).

Assume that
$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^N f_i(t) a_i\right) \cdot b = 0 \qquad \forall b \in \left(\sum_{i=1}^N a_i\right)^\perp$$
Is it then true that $$\sum_{i=1}^N f_i(t) \|a_i\| = 0 \ ?$$
Or, at least, is it true that $$\sum_{i=1}^N f_i(t) \|a_i\| \le C \ ?$$

If the answer is negative, would it help to assume additionally $\sum_{i=1}^N a_i = 0$?

I feel that I should use a triangle inequality to pass from the vector identity to the scalar one, but I don't see how.

Comment: Can you solve the $N=1$ case?

Comment: What is $\tilde{\mathbb R}?$

Comment: I feel like you must have not written what you intended because as written this is very trivially false.  For instance, just let $f_i(t)=1$ for all $i$ and all $t$.

Comment: (Also as written it is completely irrelevant that the $f_i$ are functions rather than just scalar constants, since you are only looking at one value of $t$ at a time.)